# MySQL combine SELECT results in 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL newbie needs help :)

One MySQL table is [**account_user**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSPnQ.png). Field **account_group** is JSON array with parent ID's from another table [**account_group**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX8H8.png)

I want to select users, replacing ID's from **account_group** field with group names from **account_group** table.

What I have accomplished yet is:

```
SELECT
account_user.name,
account_user.email,
account_user.hash,
account_group.name AS `group`

FROM account_user
JOIN account_group ON account_group.id MEMBER OF (JSON_EXTRACT(account_group, '$'))
WHERE account_user.email = 'pavlov@kubik.com.ua'
```

[**SELECT result**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gALXh.png)

Is it possible to combine such result set, leaving only unique fields and combining **group** field to comma separated list or JSON array like [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lxU2.png) ?

Comment: Just use GROUP_CONCAT(account_group.name)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This solved my problem:

`SELECT
account_user.id,
account_user.name,
account_user.email,
account_user.hash,
GROUP_CONCAT(account_group.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS group
FROM account_user
JOIN account_group ON account_group.id MEMBER OF (JSON_EXTRACT(account_group, '$'))
WHERE account_user.email = 'pavlov@kubik.com.ua'
GROUP BY account_user.id`